# How to fetch data from Solana smart contract

Tags: anchor, python, account-data

Is there a tutorial or detailed explanation on how to fetch all the transactions from a deployed contract on Solana?
My concrete question is: I deployed a contract (https://explorer.solana.com/address/Ge74Zarei96aTUAswrMUiHDUPpTCk427XBX7Syby71wQ?cluster=devnet) and want to fetch all the accounts that were created when the function "start_stuff_off" was called. My attempt was been using anchor-py, as shown below:

```
client = AsyncClient("https://api.devnet.solana.com")
acc = await BaseAccount.fetch(client, adrr_contract)
```

whereas BaseAccount is auto-generated using the ClientGenerator from anchorpy.
Any pointers/suggestions much appreciated!

PS - My current code can be found here (https://github.com/gabrielfior/solana-analytics/blob/master/Untitled.ipynb)

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way is probably to use a `getProgramAccounts` RPC call, and search for the first 8 bytes matching the discriminator of the particular type of Anchor account you're looking for.

Detailed explanation here:

https://solanacookbook.com/guides/get-program-accounts.html#facts

And Python implementation here:
https://michaelhly.github.io/solana-py/rpc/async_api/#solana.rpc.async_api.AsyncClient.get_program_accounts